# Adding Sum Row - Using Livewire (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a HTML table that I have created in Livewire and I wish to have a total row at the bottom.

In my HTML table, the user can add more rows to the table, and this is done by using an array.

I am creating a timesheet page, so I want a total row at the bottom to update after the user has clicked away from the field. I have seen this in JQuery, but not sure how to attempt this in Livewire.

Please see the below screenshot, the red numbers is where I would like to totals to update after the user finishes their input.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmZ6g.png)

My code is as follows

*Controllers\Livewire\ShowTimesheet.php*

```
..
public $entries = [];

...
public function addEntry()
{
  $this->entries[] = ['job_id' => '', 'worktype_id' => '',
  'hours_mon' => '',
  'hours_tue' => '',
  'hours_wed' => '',
  'hours_thu' => '',
  'hours_fri' => '',
  'hours_sat' => '',
  'hours_sun' => '',
   ];
}
...
```

*timesheet.blade.php*

```
...

//each entry row has 7 of these text boxes (for each day of the week). I wish to add up all the say Sunday boxes, and display this below the table

<td class='content-center px-2'>
<input type='text' name='entries[{{$index}}][hours_sun]' wire:model='entries.{{$index}}.hours_sun' class='border-2 border-gray-300 rounded w-16 text-lg p-2 text-center disabled:opacity-25' @if($day['locked'] == 1) disabled @endif>
</td>
...
```

Please let me know if you need more code, or this to be explained better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand 100% what do you mean, but try like this.

> your Model

```
class Entry extends Model
{
   protected $casts = [
       'entries' => 'array',
   ];
}
```

> your component

```
use App\Models\Entry;

    class ShowTimesheet extends Component
    {
        public $entries = [
          'job_id' => '',
          'worktype_id' => '',
          'hours_mon' => '',
          'hours_tue' => '',
          'hours_wed' => '',
          'hours_thu' => '',
          'hours_fri' => '',
          'hours_sat' => '',
          'hours_sun' => '',
        ];
       
        public function save()
        {
          $entry = new Entry;
          $entry->entries = $this->entries;
          $entry->save();
          return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

> your View file

```
<div>
    <table>
     <tr>
         <td class="content-center px-2">
            <input type="text" name="entries.hours_sat" wire:model.lazy="entries.hours_sat" @if($day['locked'] == 1) disabled @endif>
         </td>
         <td class="content-center px-2">
            <input type="text" name="entries.hours_sun" wire:model.lazy="entries.hours_sun" @if($day['locked'] == 1) disabled @endif>
         </td>
       ... "you can add more like this."
     </tr>
    </table>
    <button wire:click="save">Save</button> //save all data
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I should have included a visual of what I'm trying to achieve. I have included the following screenshot, the red numbers is where I would like to totals to update after the user finishes their input. [Screenshot on imgBB](https://ibb.co/z6C07YF)